# Best way to insert

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader

What is the best way to insert into a table. I have to insert 10,00,000 plus records in a bulk fashion. The approach which I am using right now is many simple inserts.

```
insert into Table1 values ('1','2','3','4');
insert into Table1 values ('5','2','7','4');
insert into Table1 values ('9','1','3','4');
..............
..............
.........
commit;
```

Is there a better way of doing this in 10g? Can I do this in a PL/SQL ?

I am pretty new to Oracle.

Comment: Where do these million rows come from?  Presumably, they are in some flat file somewhere or some other database somewhere, right?

Comment: @JustinCave: Yes..Using the shell script I am creating a .sql file with insert statements from the flat file and executing the same as batch process. The flat file will be available in Application Server.

Comment: So, your starting point is a flat file (either delimited or fixed width) with data in it?

Comment: Sounds like [SQL*Loader](http://www.oracleutilities.com/OSUtil/sqlldr.html) or an [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) but I'm off to bed so someone else can fill in the blanks :-). Can you post the first few lines of your file so people can help?

Comment: @JustinCave: The flat file is delimited with | (pipe). We are using sed command in unix and creating the insert statements.

Comment: Please define "best way"/"better way".  Define your criteria: Performance?  Maintainability?  Transaction management?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are starting with a delimited text file, you should get rid of the `sed` call and simply use the [SQL*Loader utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/part_ldr.htm#i436326) to load the data into the database (you could also copy the file to the database server and then use an external table which will have a very similar syntax).  Your control file would likely end up being very similar to [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm#i1004722).  Making some wild guesses about the lengths of your columns, the control file would be something like

```
load data
infile '<<name of your data file>>
into table <<name of your table>>
fields terminated by '|' 
(col1 char(5),
 col2 char(7),
 col3 char(9),
 col4 char(11),
 col5 char(13))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the suggestion but we have a challenge here. Since it is production we are completely restricted from the database access. To use Sql loader,we need to give the username/password. In the current scenario, the .sql file which we are creating is being  executed as part of batch process by the user for which the password is encrypted(We have exe to execute the .sql file). For Sql loader I think we have to explicitly give the user name and password :(

Comment: @Kanna - I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Why wouldn't you use whatever approach you use to encrypt the password in the executable that takes the INSERT statement?  Or use an OS authenticated account.  Or use a wallet.  Or, if you're less security conscious, simply store the password in a file that you don't have privileges to view.